# Is it possible to run multiple elseif blocks in the same if block?

Tags: php, if-statement

```
$foo=1;

function someFunction(){
  if($foo==0){ //-------Will test, won't execute
    bar();
  }elseif($foo==1){ //--Will test, and execute
    baz();
  }elseif($foo==2){ //--Doesn't test
    qux();
  }elseif($foo==3){ //--Doesn't test
    quux();
  }else{ //-------------Doesn't test
    death();
  } //------------------The program will skip down to here.
}
```

Let's say that baz() changes the value of $foo and it is different every time. I want my code to keep testing the elseif/else statements after the first one and run those if they are true.

I don't want to run the whole function again, (i.e. I don't care if $foo = 0 or 1). I'm looking for something like "continue;". Anyways please let me know if this is possible. Thanks. :)

EDIT** My code is actually way more complicated than this. I was just putting some code down for the sake of theory. All I want is the script to keep testing where it usually wouldn't.

Comment: You don't declare foo global, so php will error out

Comment: looks like a job for switch\case

Comment: Perhaps this should be done in a WHILE loop?

Comment: Use return; ? im not hax at php so i dont know if an emypy return will work but you can try

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to explain but my code is quite complicated so a while loop, a switch\case, and multiple ifs wouldn't work in this situation. There are actually a lot more checks than just $foo. I just wanna know if I can continue in my if block?

Comment: I think this is an issue with the logic of your functionality rather than the code. It sounds as if your code and the logic you require don't match up. You need to pin down how the logic should work first because if while loop, switch and elseifs won't work I can't see what option you've left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to do each consecutive `elseif`, regardless of whether previous `if`/`elseif`s matched, but you also want some code to run if *none* of the `if`/`elseif`s match. In this case, you can set a flag `$matched` to be set to `true` if one of them matches and use `if`s instead.

```
<?php
$foo=1;
function someFunction(){
  $matched = false;
  if($foo==0){
    bar();
    $matched = true;
  }
  if($foo==1){ //--This elseif will get executed, and after it's executed,
    baz();
    $matched = true;
  }
  if($foo==2){
    qux();
    $matched = true;
  }
  if($foo==3){
    quux();
    $matched = true;
  }
  if(!$matched){ /* Only run if nothing matched */
    death();
  }
}
```

If you also want to be able to skip to the end, use [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) (but [see this first](http://xkcd.com/292/)):

```
<?php
$foo=1;
function someFunction(){
  $matched = false;
  if($foo==0){
    bar();
    $matched = true;
    goto end: // Skip to end
  }
  if($foo==1){ //--This elseif will get executed, and after it's executed,
    baz();
    $matched = true;
  }
  if($foo==2){
    qux();
    $matched = true;
  }
  if($foo==3){
    quux();
    $matched = true;
  }
  if(!$matched){ /* Only run if nothing matched */
    death();
  }
  end:
}
```

Comment: It appears the OP required it to work as if "someFunction" had a loop that checked the value of $foo after each "elseif" until such a time that it no-longer equals 1, 2, or 3 after the function in the elseif code is executed. However the OP can't use a loop, or a switch or elseifs........

Comment: Yes exactly. This answer would work. :) But for the sake of learning, I am still curious to know if there is any way to have my script continue and check the other elseif/else statements?

Comment: @Aust, no: "The `elseif` statement is only executed if the preceding `if` expression and any preceding `elseif` expressions evaluated to `FALSE`, and the current `elseif` expression evaluated to `TRUE`." The whole point of `elseif` is to *not* execute future `elseif` expressions. BUT, it *is* possible... using `goto`... but **don't do it**.

Comment: @Aust I have to agree with bfrohs - whatever your required functionality is (& I think you have us all confused about what you need!) **do not use goto**. Its bad practice - if you think your code is complicated now, wait until you're trying to trace through where its gone wrong with gotos sending the execution off in unknown directions!!

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I don't need to use goto in my code so that won't be a problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is whay you mean but you can use a **switch** statement:

```
$foo=1;
function someFunction(){
  switch($foo==0){
    case 0:
        bar();
    case 1:
        baz();
    case 2:
        qux();
    case 3:
        quux();
    default:
        death();
}
```

Notice that the're not breaks on each case.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know how to explain but my code is quite complicated so a while loop, a switch\case, and multiple ifs wouldn't work in this situation. There are actually a lot more checks than just $foo. I just wanna know if I can continue in my if block?

Comment: Then you need to change your question to provide more information so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could just not use else if and just a bunch of ifs...

Answer (score -1):

// This response is incorrect. See comments below. Thanks!

I'm no expert, but the way I understand it, they will continue to run. If, in the future you're writing a group of `elseif()` statements and you want to leave the series when one is true, you use the `break` command.  See also `switch()`.

I'm absolutely open to correction if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, you're incorrect. `if(1==1){/*a*/}elseif(2==2){/*b*/}` is equivalent to `if(1==1){/*a*/}else{if(2==2){/*b*/}}` (`/*b*/` will be skipped every time).

Comment: Thanks @bfrohs. I appreciate the kind correction. You're explanation at the top of the page is perfect.